# KeePassXC blocking screen capture

Tags: screen-capture

I don't know if anyone will be familiar with this program and feature.

KeePassXC, a program used to store passwords, has a feature that blocks itself from being screen capture if you are using apps like Teams or Discord.

Does anyone know how that could be achieved?

I searched the internet a couple hours but I've been unable to gain any knowledge about this.

I thought that if someone could help me, that someone could be here.

Thank you

I tried to search the information online with 0 success

Comment: Android has a "this window is secure" flag "preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays". https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE I suspect you'll find similar in other OSes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

In the "View" menu, there's an option to "Allow Screen Capture". Try that, and it should work. It works for me when I need to remote into a computer with different types of remote access software and I can access KeePassXC remotely instead of it being grayed out. Caveat: the only trouble I've found is that "Allow Screen Caputure" doesn't stay on after a reboot. Let me know if anyone figures that out. Could be a Windows registry setting.